# Inserting Gist in WordPress post not working with java gist files

Tags: wordpress, github, gist

From morning i am trying to add gist file to my WordPress blog post but inserting java gist file is not working. below is url to my java gist file 
https://gist.github.com/amaryadav344/6a51812b951d81e611810967dfdbe656#file-adapter-java  
XML gist files are loading perfectly below is sample working correctly in XML 
https://gist.github.com/amaryadav344/6a51812b951d81e611810967dfdbe656#file-activity_main-xml

then what is problem with java gist file

Comment: "not working" - How are we supposed to know in what way it's not working? That's right... you're supposed to tell us.

Comment: Its not showing gist file in post preview for Java gist file And for XML gist file its showing  gist correctly in preview

Comment: Have you checked to see if gist files work inside Wordpress preview?

Comment: yes here it is https://en.support.wordpress.com/gist/